# On which days should one not study the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, indra, sin

From [Brahmanda Purana's Anusanga Pada Chp35](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362853.html)

> 28-30. There are fifteen Vājins. They are the disciples of Yājñavalkya viz.—Kaṇva, Baudheya Madhyandina, his son, Vaidheya, Addha, Bauddhaka, Tāpanīya, Vatsa, Jābāla, Kevala, Āvaṭī, Puṇḍra, Vaiṇoya and Parāśara.[7] These are mentioned as Vājins. They are fifteen excellent men. The branches of Yajur Mantras should be known as one hundred and one.

> 31. Jaimini taught his son Sumantu.[8] Sumantu taught his son Sutvan.

> 32-33. Sutvan taught his son Sukarman. Sukarman quickly studied a thousand Saṃhitās and expounded them to a thousand disciples who had the splendour of the sun. As they were studying during the days (when they should not be studied) Indra slew them.

> 34. Thereafter, for the sake of his disciples he performed Protest fast unto death (Prāyopaveśana). On seeing him furious, Indra granted him a boon.

Now my question is with respect to verses 32-33. Where can I find references to the days on which studying Vedas is prohibited ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many such occasions and days when Veda study is forbidden. Those are enumerated in Manu Smriti 4.101 onwards:

> 4.101. Let him who studies always avoid (reading) on the following occasions when the Veda-study is forbidden, and (let) him who teaches
> pupils according to the prescribed rule (do it likewise).

Then the text gives a long list of forbidden occasions:

> 4.102. Those who know the (rules of) recitation declare that in the rainy season the Veda-study must be stopped on these two (occasions),
> when the wind is audible at night, and when it whirls up the dust in
> the day-time
>
> 4.103. Manu has stated, that when lightning, thunder, and rain (are observed together), or when large fiery meteors fall on all sides, the
> recitation must be interrupted until the same hour (on the next day,
> counting from the occurrence of the event)
>
> 4.104. When one perceives these (phenomena) all together (in the twilight), after the sacred fires have been made to blaze (for the
> performance of the Agnihotra), then one must know the recitation of
> the Veda to be forbidden, and also when clouds appear out of season.
>
> 4.105. On (the occasion of) a preternatural sound from the sky, (of) an earthquake, and when the lights of heaven are surrounded by a halo,
> let him know that (the Veda-study must be) stopped until the same hour
> (on the next day), even if (these phenomena happen) in the (rainy)
> season.
>
> 4.106. But when lightning and the roar of thunder (are observed) after the sacred fires have been made to blaze, the stoppage shall last as
> long as the light (of the sun or of the stars is visible); if the
> remaining (above-named phenomenon, rain, occurs, the reading shall
> cease), both in the day-time and at night.
>
> 4.107. For those who wish to acquire exceedingiy great merit, a continual interruption of the Veda-study (is prescribed) in villages
> and in towns, and (the Veda-study must) always (cease) when any kind
> of foul smell (is perceptible).
>
> 4.108. In a village where a corpse lies, in the presence of a (man who lives as unrighteously as a) Sudra, while (the sound of) weeping (is
> heard), and in a crowd of men the (recitation of the Veda must be)
> stopped.
>
> 4.109. In water, during the middle part of the night, while he voids excrements, or is impure, and after he has partaken of a funeral
> dinner, a man must not even think in his heart (of the sacred texts).
>
> 4.110. A learned Brahmana shall not recite the Veda during three days, when he has accepted an invitation to a (funeral rite) in honour of
> one ancestor (ekoddishta), or when the king has become impure through
> a birth or death in his family (sutaka), or when Rahu by an eclipse
> makes the moon impure.
>
> 4.111. As long as the smell and the stains of the (food given) in honour of one ancestor remain on the body of a learned Brahmana, so
> long he must not recite the Veda.
>
> 4.112. While lying on a bed, while his feet are raised (on a bench), while he sits on his hams with a cloth tied round his knees, let him
> not study, nor when he has eaten meat or food given by a person impure
> on account of a birth or a death
>
> 4.113. Nor during a fog, nor while the sound of arrows is audible, nor during both the twilights, nor on the newmoon day, nor on the
> fourteenth and the eighth (days of each half-month), nor on the
> full-moon day.
>
> **4.114. The new-moon day destroys the teacher, the fourteenth (day) the pupil, the eighth and the full-moon days (destroy all remembrance
> of) the Veda; let him therefore avoid (reading on) those (days).**
>
> 4.115. A Brahmana shall not recite (the Veda) during a dust-storm, nor while the sky is preternaturally red, nor while jackals howl, nor
> while the barking of dogs, the braying of donkeys, or the grunting of
> camels (is heard), nor while (he is seated) in a company

So, as far as the monthly days are concerned, Purnima, Amavasya, two Chaturdashis and two Ashtamis are stated as forbidden days for Veda study.

EDIT:

List of occasions when Vedic study needs to be suspended is found in Gautama Dharma Sutras 16.5--16.49 as well:

> 5 He should suspend vedic recitation during daytime when the wind
> whirls up the dust; 6 at night when he can hear the wind blow; 7 when
> the sound of a lute, drum, side drum, chariot, or wailing is heard; 8
> when dogs are barking, jackals are howling, and donkeys are braying; 9
> when the sky turns crimson; when a rainbow appears; when there is
> frost on the ground; 10 when clouds appear out of season; 11 when he
> has the urge to void urine or excrement; 12 in the middle of the
> night, at the time of twilight, and while standing in water; 13 when
> it is raining–– 14 but, according to some, only when the water is
> running down the eaves––; 15 when Venus and Jupiter are surrounded by
> halos, 16 as also the sun and the moon; 17 when he is frightened,
> travelling in a vehicle, lying down, or has lifted his feet; 18 when
> he is in a cremation ground, at the village boundary, on a highway, or
> in an impure state; 19 when there is a foul smell; when there is a
> corpse or a Chandala in the village; when a S´udra is near by; 20 and
> when he experiences an acrid belching.21 The recitation of the Rgveda
> and the Yajurveda, moreover, is suspended as long as the recitation of
> the Sa¯maveda is heard.
>
> 22 When there is a lightning strike, an earthquake, an eclipse, or the
> fall of a meteor, vedic recitation is suspended until the same time
> the next day; 23 as also when there is thunder, rain, or lightning
> during twilight when the fires are visible. 24 When these happen
> during the rainy season, however, the suspension lasts only that day.
> 25 When there is lightning during the night, moreover, the suspension
> lasts until the last watch of the night; 26 but if it occurs during or
> after the third part of the day, the suspension lasts the whole night.
>
> 27 According to some, a meteor has the same effect as lightning with
> respect to the suspension of vedic recitation, 28 as does thunder when
> it occurs in the afternoon 29 or even at dusk. 30 If there is thunder
> before midnight, the suspension lasts for the whole night; 31 if it
> happens during the day, the suspension lasts throughout the daylight
> hours, 32 as also when the king of that realm dies, 33 and when one
> student goes on a journey and another stays behind with the teacher.
> 34 The suspension lasts for a day and a night when there has been a
> social disturbance or a fire; when he has finished reciting one Veda;
> when he has vomited; when he has eaten at an ancestral offering or at
> a sacrifice to humans ; 35 on the new-moon day–– 36 alternatively, the
> suspension here may last for two days––; 37 and on the full-moon days
> of the lunar months October–November, February–March, and June–July.
> 38 At the three eighth-day offerings during the three fortnights of
> the waning moon following the full moon of November– December, the
> suspension lasts for three days; 39 according to some, the suspension
> takes place only at the last of these eighthday offerings. 40 When the
> annual course of study is commenced and concluded, the suspension is
> in effect on that day, as well as on the preceding and following days.
> 41 In the opinion of all authorities, when rain, lightning, and
> thunder occur together, the suspension lasts for three days, 42 as
> also when there is heavy rain. 43 On a festive day vedic recitation is
> suspended after the meal. Immediately after commencing the annual
> course of study.recitation is suspended during the first four ‘hours’
> of the night. 45 According to some, vedic recitation is always
> suspended in a town. 46 Even mental recitation is suspended when a
> person is impure. 47 After making an ancestral offering, the
> suspension lasts until the same time the next day, 48 as also when
> uncooked food is distributed at an ancestral offering. 49 Vedic
> recitation is also suspended for reasons given in each vedic branch.